# Reusing calculated value in mysql select statment

Tags: mysql, select

I need to reuse once calculate variable again in my select statement.
Is there any way to acieve it?

```
SELECT 
user_id,
SUM(duration) as loggedhours,
COUNT(DISTINCT(DATE(timestamp_start))) as working_day,
working_day*9 as available_hours
FROM dev_new__copy.timesheet
WHERE timestamp_start > '2019-10-02 18:30:00.000' 
GROUP BY user_id;
```

However this throws an error.
I have also trie saving it in var and reusing but that fails too.

```
SELECT 
user_id,
SUM(duration) as loggedhours,
@working_day := COUNT(DISTINCT(DATE(timestamp_start))) as working_day,
@working_day*9 as available_hours
FROM dev_new__copy.timesheet
WHERE timestamp_start > '2019-10-02 18:30:00.000' 
GROUP BY user_id;
```

However the available hours is not correct. Any hint would be appreciated

Comment: Could you display the error message?

Comment: @PauloTomé i think it is *Unknown column 'working_day' in 'field list'*.

Comment: Calculations like that are insignificant compared to all the other operations going on.  Don't worry about that optimization.  To see the difference, time the query with and without including `available_hours`.

Answer (score 0):

Test two variants:

```sql
SELECT user_id,
       SUM(duration) as loggedhours,
       COUNT(DISTINCT(DATE(timestamp_start))) as working_day,
       COUNT(DISTINCT(DATE(timestamp_start)))*9 as available_hours
FROM dev_new__copy.timesheet
WHERE timestamp_start > '2019-10-02 18:30:00.000' 
GROUP BY user_id;
```

and

```sql
SELECT user_id, loggedhours, working_day, 9*working_day available_hours
FROM ( SELECT user_id,
              SUM(duration) as loggedhours,
              COUNT(DISTINCT(DATE(timestamp_start))) as working_day
       FROM dev_new__copy.timesheet
       WHERE timestamp_start > '2019-10-02 18:30:00.000' 
       GROUP BY user_id ) x;
```

If the amount of output records is low then 2nd variant will be more effective.

If the amount of output records is huge then 1st variant must be more effective.

Only the test on real data may show what is more effective on your data array.

Comment: Hi, The first one is correct and working. However I do not want to go with this approach, since mysql will have to calculate COUNT(DISTINCT(DATE(timestamp_start))) twice.THat is exactly what i wanted to avoid

Comment: @AbhishekAnand *mysql will have to calculate COUNT(DISTINCT(DATE(timestamp_start))) twice* That's right... but the calculation of its argument and its sorting will be reused. Check est. time for 1nd query and while commenting `available_hours` field - the difference must be not more than 20-25%, and not twice.

Comment: @AbhishekAnand 2nd query is NOT applicable if the amount of OUTPUT records is too high (i.e. when subquery result is cached on disk). But I doubt you have such many user ids.